# Download Link/Button to a game

Tags: javascript, html, unity-game-engine

Recently I made a simple game in Unity and I want to make a website for this project. So my question is: How I can add a download link to my game? (And when I press the link or the button to download the game, a zip file, or an installer)

Comment: Most browsers will download a zip file if you navigate to a page like `http://example.com/PathToZip.zip`

Comment: I will try it when I have time. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have domain and hosting?

If you have, you should make an easy html web site, or you can find free templates with search. Then you can edit it and you can deploy it to hosting.

Comment: i don't have a domain and hosting. I just want to create a simple plan to this project and I think this hole thing with downloading the game is a great idea. Now I am trying to find want I really need to know and do to make it. Thank you!

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but if you want people to download your game from a website, you will need a website and therefore need a domain and hosting.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use:

```
<form method="get" action="your-game-file.zip">
    <button type="submit">Download My Game!</button>
</form>
```

This simply creates a mini form, and actions the document or file you want when the button is clicked. ;p

Comment: you could forgo the form and just use `<button onclick="window.open('your-game-file.zip')">Download My Game!</button>`

Comment: sorry but I simply write the name of the zip file or do i need to put the file somewhere? I don't undersand. Excuse me, I am a noob.

Comment: In a html file `body` section, you can add in the code above, and simply link the file to your directory. For example, if your html file is in a folder named _game_ and your zip file is in that same folder, you'd just need to state your zip file name. Your file *will* need to be accessible by the html document. There's a great but short read about file paths here: https://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/ and you can go more in to depth about forms here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp